# Numpad dot in python

Tags: python, add-on

I would like to center the view3d on a selected object, just like numpad "." (dot) do.
i saw we can use  `bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis(type='LEFT')` for exemple but i can't find how to center the view on an object with python.

Does anybody have an idea ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have Python Tooltips enabled in your Preferences:

[image: python tooltips and developer extras options]

That way, when you hover something to get its tooltip, it displays the python command it actually calls. So taking the example of `Frame Selected` which is what you are trying to do, we see this:

[image: frame selected's tooltip]

And thanks to Developer Extras, you can <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> → `Copy Python Command` so that it copies `bpy.ops.view3d.view_selected(use_all_regions=False)` in your clipboard and you can paste it into any sript you want.

Comment: thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

Note that to use that Python command in a script, the current context needs to be temporarily overridden to provide a 3D view area and a window region, like this:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

areas = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D']
if len(areas) > 0:
    context_override = context.copy()
    context_override['area'] = areas[0]
    context_override['region'] = [region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW'][0]
    with context.temp_override(**context_override):
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_selected()
```

See [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html) for more information about contexts.